# question about sets

Tags: elementary-set-theory, discrete-mathematics

I have this as a beggining to a question:

$A\subseteq Z^2$

$$
A = \left \langle \left ( 1,7 \right );\left ( 7,2 \right );(2,3) \right \rangle = \left \{  \right.n_{1}*(1,7)+n_{2}*(7,2)+n_{3}*(2,3)\left.  \right \},\left \{  \right.n_{i}\in Z\left.  \right \}
$$

I understand the first part, $A$ is a subset of $Z^2$, which means $A$ is a set of ordered pairs in $Z^2$.

I don't understand the second part. how did the $n1,n2,n3$ get there and how is $A$ suddenly a sum of numbers?

Thanks in advance,

Yaron.

Answer (score 2):

The second part is the definition of $A$. $A$ is defined as the subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ generated by $(1,7),(7,2),(2,3)$, meaning that $A$ is the set of ordered pairs of integers that can be expressed as a linear combination of those three ordered couples with integers coefficients.

You can prove that $A$ is the smallest subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ that contains $(1,7),(7,2)$ and $(2,3)$, i.e. if $B$ is a subgroup of $\mathbb{Z}^2$ and $B$ contains $(1,7),(7,2)$ and $(2,3)$, then $B$ also contains $A$.